# How can I make the angle in $\langle$ and $\rangle$ more acute?

Tags: formatting, symbols

The standard \langle and \rangle don't seem acute enough for me. I also do not want it to be too acute, like in $<$. An example I have in my mind is the following:

[image]

My attempt was to draw it, as below,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\customlangle}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw coordinate (a) at (.35,1);
    \draw coordinate (b) at (0,.5);
    \draw coordinate (c) at (.35,0);
    \draw (a) -- (b) -- (c);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
\newcommand{\customrangle}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw coordinate (a) at (0,1);
    \draw coordinate (b) at (.35,.5);
    \draw coordinate (c) at (0,0);
    \draw (a) -- (b) -- (c);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

This is a line of text with a custom angle symbol: \customlangle \customrangle

\end{document}
```

The result is as follows;

[image]

How do I make the tikzpicture be compatible with line height? I would want it to be the same size as \langle.

Comment: tex has no control  over the shape of letters. It's like asking to change the shape of `a` or `g`   Just choose a font that you like.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I edited the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of TikZ default unit of centimetre, you could use one relative to the font, e.g. `ex`:

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\customlangle}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=0.5ex]
    \draw coordinate (a) at (.35ex,2.2ex);
    \draw coordinate (b) at (0,1.1ex);
    \draw coordinate (c) at (.35ex,0);
    \draw[line width=0.12ex,line cap=round] (a) -- (b) -- (c);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
\newcommand{\customrangle}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=0.5ex]
    \draw coordinate (a) at (0,2.2ex);
    \draw coordinate (b) at (.35ex,1.1ex);
    \draw coordinate (c) at (0,0);
    \draw[line width=0.12ex,line cap=round] (a) -- (b) -- (c);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

Symbol: $\langle$ \customlangle \customrangle

\Huge Symbol  \customlangle \customrangle

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Start with this MWE:

```latex
\documentclass[margin=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
% \usepackage[math]{kurier}
% \usepackage{newpx}
\usepackage{newtx}
\begin{document}
$|\langle Tf, g \rangle|$
\end{document}
```

[image: |<Tf,g>|]

and then go through https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/mathfonts.html until you find a font that you like.